# Bootstrap dynamic form is not aligned

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic

I am making a dynamic form with multiple fields in bootstrap and when I add a new inline form, it is not aligned with the previous one. I appreciate if someone can help me with that.

[image of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhKDf.png)

html:

```
<!-- start of the column with properties(form-control)-->
  <div class="col-lg-8" id="property-col">
    <div class="container">
      <form class="form">

      <div class="row">
        <h3>Properties</h3>
        <br>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
          <fieldset class="form-inline">
            <label class="control-label">Image Size:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="image-size-selector">
              <option value="128">128×128</option>
              <option value="256">256×256</option>
              <option value="512">512×512</option>
              <option value="1024">1024×1024</option>
            </select>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row" id="dynamic_form">
        <div class="form-group form-horizontal">
          <label>Primitives</label>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="form-inline" id="primitive_fields">
              <select class="input-small form-control" id="primitive-selector" name="PrimitiveChoose[]">
                <option value=" " disabled selected>primitive</option>
                <option value="sphere">sphere</option>
                <option value="triangle">triangle</option>
              </select>
              <input type="number" class="input-small form-control" id="diameter"  name="Diameter[]" step="any" placeholder="diameter(D)">
              <input type="text" class="input-small form-control"  id="sphere-position" name="SpherePosition[]"  placeholder="(x, y, z)">
              <select class="input-small form-control" id="circle-color-selector" name="CircColorSelect[]" >
                <option value=" " disabled selected>color</option>
                <option value="red">red</option>
                <option value="blue">blue</option>
                <option value="green">green</option>
                <option value="yellow">yellow</option>    
              </select> 
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add" id="add_more"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

css:

```
.form-inline  .input-mini
{
    width: 70px;
    font-weight: bold;
}


.form-inline  .input-small
{
    width: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
}


#primitive-form > *
{
    margin: 2px 2px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm maybe you need to create a codepen.

It seems align if not created dynamically.

http://codepen.io/seiran/pen/LWwWgX

Try to post your script.

```
//code is the same -- dont mind this
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking this type of format here i executed with the single input so you can add your own new things.

The fieldset is closed on the first form itself just cut the fieldset there with the belowed two div and paste at the end.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var next = 1;
    $(".add-more").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var addto = "#field" + next;
        var addRemove = "#field" + (next);
        next = next + 1;
        var newIn = '<input autocomplete="off" class="input form-control" id="field' + next + '" name="field' + next + '" type="text">';
        var newInput = $(newIn);
        var removeBtn = '<button id="remove' + (next - 1) + '" class="btn btn-danger remove-me" >-</button></div><div id="field">';
        var removeButton = $(removeBtn);
        $(addto).before(newInput);
        $(addRemove).before(removeButton);

            $('.remove-me').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1);
                var fieldID = "#field" + fieldNum;
                $(this).remove();
                $(fieldID).remove();
            });
    });



});

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <input type="hidden" name="count" value="1" />
               <div class="controls" id="profs"> 
                        <form class="input-append">
                            <div id="field"><input autocomplete="off" class="input" id="field1" name="prof1" type="text" placeholder="Type something" data-items="8"/><button id="b1" class="btn add-more" type="button">+</button></div>
                        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```